# My R function for finding what percent of the population lies within k standard deviation of the mean, does not work

Tags: r, loops

```
whatpercent <- function(x) {
 i<-1
 for(i in length(x)) {
 if(x[i]<= mean(x)+sd(x)) {
 vec <- c(vec,x[i])
 }
 else{
 next
}
}
percent <- length(vec)/length(x)
percent <- percent * 100
return(percent)
}
```

Okay I seem to get the same thing when I use

```
whatpercent(mydata,1) whatpercent(mydata,2) whatpercent(mydata,3) ...
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Try `for(i in 1:length(x) ) { .... }`. You do not loop with your code.

Comment: Yeh ofc! But now this time I get length(vec)>= length(x)

Comment: You define the function to take one argument, `x`, but you supply it with two arguments when you call it (e.g. `whatpercent(mydata, 1)`).

Comment: As written, the function only checks for values less than or equal to one standard deviation above the mean. Where is the 'k'?

Comment: Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple function which should achieve what you want. For tasks like this you should work with vectorized functions in order to avoid loops. It also makes your code much cleaner and easier to read.

```
whatpercent <- function(x, k) {
    mean(abs(x - mean(x)) <= sd(x) * k)
}

#Example
x <- rnorm(100)
whatpercent(x,2)
[1] 0.95
```

Comment: Any thoughts on if it would be more efficient (for large vectors) to store `mean(x)` and `sd(x)` before the `ifelse` call?

Comment: The `ifelse` is not necessary. Just use the condition.

Comment: True, much simpler ;)